# Assign a name to a physical device in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I have two Pixel 4s connected for testing/debugging. They both show up as `Google Pixel 4 [uniqueID]`. Is there a way to change the displayed name, to make it easier to tell them apart without me having to remember each uniqueID?